# Adjust clutch on toyota tazz...

Tags: toyota, clutch

I took my car in for a service. Upon receiving it back I have to push the clutch in to it's absolute max before shifting gears. It wasn't like this before. If I can describe in terms of percentages it was as follow. The first 30% was freeplay. From 30 to 85 was actual clutch. The last 15% was freeplay.

How can this be adjusted?

Comment: what year and engine size?

Comment: First off, you should bring it back to whoever did the "service" on your car and complain. If it was working well before they touched it, then they broke it / messed it up then they should fix it (for free too)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a clutch cable there is a nut to adjust where the cable mounts to the transmission. If you have hydraulic clutch there is not an adjustment, check your fluid level, low fluid could cause this, but this indicates an additional problem.

Comment: I have a clutch cable. Can you explain the steps I need to take to do this?

Comment: @abrian I need the engine size and year

Comment: Will get this asap!

Comment: Toyota Tazz 1300 5 Speed 2003